# Populate a WTForms selectfield with data coming from firestore

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore, wtforms

So... I'm trying to dynamically fill option from a `selectfield` using data coming from a `firestore` database.
I initialise a new object from my Items class, I load my form named `AjouterForm()`, then I call my function `getItemsDB()` that populate the var `fields` (it's a list) using data from firestore db, and finally I try to populate the selectfield `itemFields`.

I can launch the program but when I go on "ajouter" I get an error :

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

routes.py

```
@app.route("/ajouter", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ajouter():
    try:
        items = Items()
        form = AjouterForm()
        items.getItemsDB()
        form.itemsFields.choices = items.fields
    except ValueError:
        flash("Problème", 'danger')
    return render_template('ajouter.html', title='Ajouter', form=form)
```

ajouter.html

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Ajouter</legend>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.type.label }}
                        {{ form.type }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.customer.label }}
                        {{ form.customer }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="output">
                <div id="INVOICE" class="hidden INVOICE">
                <!--A compléter-->
                </div>
                <div id="ORDER" class="hidden ORDER">
                    {{ form.block.label }}
                    {{ form.block }}
                </div>
                <div id="SERVICE_REQUEST" class="hidden SERVICE_REQUEST">
                <!--A compléter-->
                </div>
                <div class="output2">
                    <div id="ITEMS" class="hidden2 ITEMS">
                        {{ form.itemsFields.label }}
                        {{ form.itemsFields }}
                    </div>
                    <div id="PARTNERS">

                    </div>
                    <div id="fields">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class AjouterForm(FlaskForm):
    type = SelectField("Type", choices=[("INVOICE","invoice"), ("ORDER","order"), ("SERVICE_REQUEST", "service_request")], id="type")
    block = SelectField("Block", choices=[("ITEMS","items"), ("PARTNERS","partners"), ("fields","fields")], id="block")
    itemsFields = SelectField("Champs", choices=[], coerce=list, id="itemsField")
    tailleDocX = IntegerField("Taille X", validators=[DataRequired()])
    tailleDocY = IntegerField("Taille Y", validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer = SelectField("Customer", choices=[("mlt", "mlt")])
    submit = SubmitField('Confirmer')
```

models.py

```
class Items(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = []

    def getItemsDB(self):
        doc_ref = db.collection("customizing").document("FORMS")
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        datas = doc.get("ORDER").get("ITEMS").get("fields")
        for data in datas:
            self.fields.append(data)
```

I'm kinda new to python, flask and firestore database and I can't manage to find what is causing this error, hope my english isn't to bad ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY I FIXED IT !

I found out that selectfields only accept tuple, I did this :

```
items = Items()
        items.getItemsDB()
        form.itemsFields.choices = []
        for fields in items.fields:
            form.itemsFields.choices += [(fields, fields)]
```